# Google DFP - Refresh AD slot without New Impression Count

Tags: javascript, tags, google-dfp

I need to refresh all ad slots after 15 sec and load new ads to the slots without counting new impression. 
** This works :

```
googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1], {changeCorrelator: false});
```

**but when I add the set interval 30 sec.. it is not refreshing-

```
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh(null, {changeCorrelator: false}, 30000)});
```

Pls help..Tnx

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
setInterval(function, milliseconds)
```

The code bellow should work:

```
setInterval(function(){
    googletag.pubads().refresh(null, {changeCorrelator: false});
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to the fact that the `refresh()` call should be **pushed** to `googletag` commands. So this should solve your issue:

```
setInterval(function(){
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
         // refresh fetches a new ad for each slot, without changing the correlator.
        googletag.pubads().refresh(null, {changeCorrelator: false});
    });
}, 30000);
```

Please note this line in th example above: 
**googletag.cmd.push(function() {...});**